# Writing custom Shiro realm

Tags: security, authentication, authorization, shiro

I am constructing my own `AuthorizingRealm` subclass, and am having a tough time wiring it up to my `SecurityManager`.

The essence of my realm:

```java
public class MyRealm extends AuthorizingRealm { 
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException { 
        try { 
            // My custom logic here 

        } catch(Throwable t) { 
            System.out.println(t.getMessage()); 
        } 
        SimpleAuthenticationInfo authn = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(new MyUser(), "somePassword");
        return authn;
    } 

    protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) { 
        try { 
            // My custom logic here 
        } catch(Throwable t) { 
            System.out.println(t.getMessage()); 
        }
        return new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();
    } 
}
```

Then in my 'shiro.ini':

```
# ======================= 
# Shiro INI configuration 
# ======================= 
[main] 
myRealm = com.me.myapp.security.MyRealm
```

Then in my Driver class/main method (that I'm using for testing):

```java
public class Driver { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Driver d = new Driver(); 
        d.test(); 
    } 

    public void test() { 
        Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini"); 
        SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance(); 
        SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager); 

        UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken("", ""); 
        token.setRememberMe(true); 

        System.out.println("Shiro props:"); 
        System.out.println(securityManager.getProperties()); 

        Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject() 

        try { 
            currentUser.login(token) 

            println "I think this worked!" 
        } catch (UnknownAccountException uae) { 
            println "Exception: ${uae}" 
        } catch (IncorrectCredentialsException ice) { 
            println "Exception: ${ice}" 
        } catch (LockedAccountException lae) { 
            println "Exception: ${lae}" 
        } catch (ExcessiveAttemptsException eae) { 
            println "Exception: ${eae}" 
        } catch (AuthenticationException ae) { 
            println "Exception: ${ae}" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

When I run this I get:

```
Shiro props: 
[class:class org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager, cacheManager:null, subjectFactory:org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSubjectFactory@6a2b8b42, authorizer:org.apache.shiro.authz.ModularRealmAuthorizer@50c3d082, realms:[com.me.myapp.security.MyRealm@67ae303a], subjectDAO:org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSubjectDAO@5ce06503, rememberMeManager:null, authenticator:org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator@1007d798, sessionManager:org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionManager@72db4460] 
Exception: org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed for token submission [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - , rememberMe=true].  Possible unexpected error? (Typical or expected login exceptions should extend from AuthenticationException).
```

So it looks like its reading my shiro.ini because its picking up the correct realm, but `MyRealm` doesn't do anything except stub out dummy users that should authenticated regardless of the username/password supplied. Any ideas as to where I'm going awry?

Answer (score 0):

add this to your shiro.ini: `securityManager.realms = $myRealm` 
then in your Driver class

```
UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken("", "somePassword");
```

instead of an empty passowrd.

I think this worked!

Comment: Thanks @Luca Rasconi, however your suggestions don't change anything (same behavior as I describe above). Any other thoughts/ideas? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this myself, but here are a couple of things you can try:

1. If you don't need authorization logic, consider subclassing AuthenticatingRealm instead of AuthorizingRealm
2. In method doGetAuthenticationInfo, consider using this code:

   SimpleAuthenticationInfo authn = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(token.getPrincipal(), token.getCredentials(), "myRealm");

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have created a Realm properly but have not told the `SecurityManager` that it is one the realms to be used. In that way, it is just another object created in the `main` section of `shiro.ini`.

To tell Shiro's `SecurityManager` that it needs to use `myRealm` as a Realm, you need to add this to your `shiro.ini`:

```
securityManager.realms = $myRealm
```